# CSS is there anything like float: up?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a layout like a dash board with multiple divs that I would like to have two columns when the browser is wider than a certain width. http://jsfiddle.net/p8pts/1/

I am trying to do a `float:left;` and change the width to 50%

When the screen is narrow it looks like this

[image: Narrow Browser Width]

and when the browser is wider than the specified width I want it to look like this

[image: Wide Browser Width]

but it actually comes out like this

[image]

The divs are all variable heights. Is there anything I can do without complicated javascript to figure out positioning? Preferably using css?

Edit: I have seen masonry and it does what I want except that some of my divs have moving heights with jquery's slideDown method so absolute positioning won't work.

Comment: By searching google, this looks like a pretty common need for pintrest style divs. Could we get this into a w3c standard? I think float: up would be perfect syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a masonry layout with pure CSS you can use the Flexible Box Layout.

You can see an example of what you need here (try making the window wider/narrower): http://jsfiddle.net/ds75Q/

This is all the CSS I've used:

```
div#masonry {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 900vw;
    font-size: 0;
}
div#masonry img {
    width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    div#masonry {
        display: block;
    }
    div#masonry img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Check the current support here: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Here the W3C spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-css-flexbox-1-20140325/

And here a good article, although there are many more: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**UPDATE:**

If you can't specify the parent's `height` because it will be variable, you can use CSS columns, like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2WZm/1/

For the parent you can specify the number of columns you want to use and the gap width between them:

```
div#masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

For the child elements you can change the `display` to `inline-block` and they won't be split between the columns even if their height changes: http://jsfiddle.net/p8pts/14/

```
div > span {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Or you can also use `display:block' with the property`column-break-inside:avoid` for the same effect:  jsfiddle.net/p8pts/12

```
div > span {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -o-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -ms-column-break-inside:avoid;
    column-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

Note that the `width:100%` of the child elements refers to the 100% of the column, not the parent element.

Comment: That almost works except that you have to specify a height. The height is changing all the time.

Comment: If there was a way to specify the number of columns instead of the height this would be perfect.

Comment: If the height of the columns is variable, you can create a `div` for each column and float them. Take a look to this http://jsfiddle.net/bxa69/4/ and if it works for you, tell me so I can update my answer.

Comment: Except I would have to explicitly put each of my divs in one of the two columns. I want the browser to figure out which divs should be in which columns to allow for the smallest height but I won;t know what the height will be beforehand and the height changes all the time so it will have to restack the columns without refreshing the page

Comment: OK, I didn't understand you. One parent `div` and variable height, so the CSS assigns the child elements to each column. This is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/j2WZm/1/ Made with pure CSS using the column properties. Tell me if this is working for you.

Comment: Sooooooo Close. I can't believe I didn't know about css columns. That would work exept as shown in this jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/p8pts/11/ The divs shouldn't be split between the two columns. And the jquery slide down makes the columns very jumpy and even break some times. I'm not too worried about the jumpiness but the divs must be held together or it won't work.

Comment: got it working with column-break-inside:avoid http://jsfiddle.net/p8pts/12/ if you make an answer with that I will mark it as an answer

Comment: In the first one the `div` was split because its `display` was `block` instead of `inline-block` as I suggested in my last fiddle. I think it's the same as using `column-break-inside:avoid`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/p8pts/14/

Answer (score 0):

there is no good solution in css yet. this is typically called a masonry or pinterest layout. use jquery.

try... http://masonry.desandro.com/

or google 'masonry layout plugin'

If you are tied to the css solution, use the css3 column, although this does not flow the divs horizontally, so this does not match your desired order:

```
div{
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 10px;
width: 480px; }
```

This does not work in IE9 and less, so fall back to the javascript...

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: While searching for an answer I stumbled across Masonry. The problem with absolute positioning is some of the divs have hidden divs that are shown with jquery's slideDown

Comment: That should not be a problem. If a div changes height, you would just need to call the masonary function again to recalculate the positions of the divs.

Answer (score 0):

You want them to stack like, say a Pinterest board? I don't know exactly how Pinterest did it, but I remember that they used `absolute positioning`. CSS might be possible although I think it would be a far-fetched solution.

Why reinvent the weel, have a look at [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). From the website:

`Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in use all over the Internet.`

The tiles on the homepage are stacked with Masonry, and it includes a short tutorial to get started.

It would then suffice to put all your `<div>`s in a JS for loop, and create a new Masonry object for each div. Or you can even instantiate it immediately from the HTML, it says.
Good luck.

Comment: While searching for an answer I stumbled across Masonry. The problem with absolute positioning is some of the divs have hidden divs that are shown with jquery's slideDown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered conditionals based on screen width? You can then apply CSS as necessary.

I dabbled a little bit in converting a regular monitor sized website for mobile and used CSS conditionals to achieve the desired result. It worked surprisingly WELL. The conditionals when something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

#header ul {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1.02048%; /* 10/980 */
}
#header form {
    display: none;
}
#footer p {
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #4e4e4e;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 16.3265%; /* 160/980 */
    min-width: 120px;
    margin-left: 1.0204%; /* 10/980 */
}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

#header form {
    display: block;
}
#header ul a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 74px;
}

#header div > a.mobile {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: yes I am using media queries but I don't know what to change for the css when the screen is wider

Comment: Use absolute positioning if the heights of the element boxes are fixed. Use tables if the heights will change. You can apply the positioning type of tables to regular divs via CSS. `display: table;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give this a shot (I took some liberties with the markup, so it may not be what you want):

```
<div class="left">
    <span class="sm">1</span>
    <span class="med">3</span>
    <span class='lg'>5</span>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <span class='med'>2</span>
    <span class="sm">4</span>
    <span class="lg">6</span>
    <span class="sm">8</span>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: -2px;
}

.right {
    left: 50%;
}

span {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.lg {
    height: 200px;
}

.med {
    height: 150px;
}

.sm {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8pts/10/

Comment: P.S. You win "Title of the Day" award :)

Comment: This won't work the divs are all variable height and change all the time. So I won't know which divs should go in which columns

Comment: This solution doesn't depend on the contained elements having any specific height. They'll always stack and take up 50% of the width. However if all the inner elements need to occupy the total available height and width dynamically, you'll need JS/jQuery.